# Remove blank tags with simple HTML DOM parser

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I have a html input which contains many blank strong tags. so i want to remove these blank strong tags from html.I have used simple HTML DOM but it doesn't work

```
foreach($html->find('strong') as $strong)
{

    if(trim($strong->innertext) == '')
    {
        echo 'blank strong';
    }
}
```

In above code, i have checked the if condition without trim function, but still no success .
How to remove blank tags or tags which contains only whitespace from html code ?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't give an example but lets say you have this markup, you could use `outertext`. (By the way, I can't also find a some kind of `removeChild()` on the manual).

```
$html_string = '
<div class="container">
<strong>Text1</strong>
<strong>Text2</strong>
<strong>Text3</strong>
<strong></strong>
<strong>Text5</strong>
</div>
';

$html = str_get_html($html_string);
foreach($html->find('strong') as $element) {
    if(trim($element->innertext) == '') {
        $element->outertext = '';
    }
}

echo htmlentities($html);
```

Should output:

```
<div class="container"> <strong>Text1</strong> <strong>Text2</strong> <strong>Text3</strong> <strong>Text5</strong> </div>
```

The fourth `<strong></strong>` tag should be gone now.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use jquery to remove blank tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('strong').each(function(){
        if($.trim($(this).html()) == ''){
            $(this).remove();
        }
    })
})
```

You can also use preg_replace to remove empty html tags.

```
$html = "abc<strong></strong><p>dd</p><b>non-empty</b><strong>  ashish </strong><strong><a>click</a></strong><strong>   </strong><strong>test</strong>"; 
$pattern = "/<[^\/>]*>([\s]?)*<\/[^>]*>/"; // pattern for removing all empty tags
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $html);
```

Comment: This won't help if the OP is after a serverside solution. I don't see javasctipt, let alone jquery mentioned any where in the question.

Comment: I have added another solution for removing empty html tags using php. you can use this one.